# Finding item in an array of items (object id ref) mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So i have the following  patient & Consultation schema

```
// patient schema
 
const patientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nom: {
      type: String,
      required:true
    },
    prénom: {
      type: String,
      required:true
    },
    naissance:{
      type:Date,
    },
    adresse: {
      type: String,
      required:true
    },
    téléphone: {
      type: String,
      required:true
    },
    profession: {
      type: String,
    },
    consultations:[{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:'Consultations'
    }],
    salle:{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref:'Salle'
    },
    date:{
      type:String,
      default: Date.now
    },
    jointes: {
      type:Array
    },
    questionnaire: {
      type:Object
    },
  }, { collection : 'patients'} );

 // Consultation schema

  const consultationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      date: {
        type: String,
        required:true
      },
      motif:{
        type: String,
      },

  const consultations = mongoose.model('Consultation', consultationSchema);
```

now in mongo i have a patient record with multiple consultations. i want to select a patient with a specific motif( the motif in db is "Checkin") in it. Here's my code:

```
const patient = await patients.find({consultations: {$in:["Checkin"]}}).populate({
            path:"consultations",
            model:"Consultation"
        })
```

but it doesn't return the record. all i get is an empty array. Here's the record by the way

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the patientSchema, You've spelled wrong the collection it should refer to

```
 consultations:[{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:'Consultations'
```

should be

```
 consultations:[{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:'Consultation'
```

that is whatever you put in your collection name in this case

```
  const consultations = mongoose.model('Consultation', consultationSchema);
```